# cant reset disabled iphone 6s plus

Tags: iphone, itunes

my iPhone is completely disabled due to too many failed password attempts. it says in the screen "iPhone disabled connect to iTunes" but i dont have a mac-book. i also want to reset my iPhone with the buttons but when i press and hold both power and home button (how it says you reset it) it just turns back on to the same screen that says to connect to iTunes. can someone please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Download iTunes for windows [here](https://www.apple.com/itunes/) and follow the recovery procedure.